# Is MPI on Constrained Devices a Good Choice for Inter Process Communication on Linux?

Tags: linux, mpi, posix, ipc

I have to design and deploy an application for a *relatively* constrained device such as a [Raspberry Pi 4 Model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/). My idea is to deploy several processes that are able to communicate them through IPC (Inter Process Communication).

I am evaluating the several options and it's easy to understand that the Shared Memory solution has the best performance at the cost of bigger development time. With the following trend:

1. **Shared Memory**. Faster, but less portable and difficult to implement
2. **Pipes**.
3. **Message Queues**.
4. **Sockets**. Slower, but more portable and easy to implement

[This](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~adityav/Evaluation_of_Inter_Process_Communication_Mechanisms.pdf) is a reference, but there is other material on the web about.
All the 3 solutions are good options, but I am afraid that if one day the implementation must be altered, then there may be problems.

I am thinking that MPI could be a good option for keeping the right level of abstraction, but I am scared that the additional layer of machine agnostic introduced by it may slow down the application.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have rephased the question. It was a bit confusing indeed.

Answer (score 1):

MPI, in general, isn't a good *general purpose* abstraction. MPI is at its best in  scientific simulations where structured data needs to be distributed. Contrary, MPI doesn't provide particularly helpful abstractions for use cases which require RPCs or master/worker task queues. That said, you can map almost any IPC use-case to MPI, but you may be better of with a paradigm that provides a higher level of abstraction to your use-case.

Nevertheless, MPI is generally optimized for performance and implementations can leverage shared memory underneath. Of course you will always have the cost of explicit communication (API calls) as opposed to accessing memory directly.